# How do you replace repeating elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```
[1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 9, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

and want to replace the repeating values with a string `"repeat"`. The repeated `4` at indices `1`, `2`, `3` and `3` at indices `8`, `9`, `10`, `11` should be replaced. I should get:

```
[1, "repeat", 2, 9, 0, 4, "repeat", 4]
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints. What have you tried? Why didn't it work? If you didn't try, why not?

Answer (score 9):

Here are two ways you could do that.

**#1 Use [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):**

```
arr = [1,4,4,4,2,9,0,4,3,3,3,3,4]

arr.chunk(&:itself).map { |f,a| a.size==1 ? f : "repeat" }
  #=> [1, "repeat", 2, 9, 0, 4, "repeat", 4]
```

The steps:

```
enum = arr.chunk(&:itself)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007febc99fb160>:each>
```

We can view the elements of this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, [1]], [4, [4, 4, 4]], [2, [2]], [9, [9]], [0, [0]],
  #    [4, [4]], [3, [3, 3, 3, 3]], [4, [4]]]
```

[Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) was added in Ruby v2.2. For earlier version you would use

```
enum = arr.chunk { |e| e }
```

It is now a simple matter to map the elements of `enum` as required:

```
enum.map { |f,a| a.size==1 ? f : "repeat" }
  #=> [1, "repeat", 2, 9, 0, 4, "repeat", 4]
```

**#2 Use [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when)**

```
arr.slice_when { |e,f| e !=f }.map { |a| a.size==1 ? a.first : "repeat" }
```

The steps:

```
enum = arr.slice_when { |e,f| e !=f } 
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007febc99b8cc0>:each> 
a = enum.to_a
  #=> [[1], [4, 4, 4], [2], [9], [0], [4], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4]] 
a.map { |a| a.size==1 ? a.first : "repeat" } 
  #=> [1, "repeat", 2, 9, 0, 4, "repeat", 4]
```

`slice_when` was introduced in Ruby v.2.2.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Object#itself` is new in Ruby 2.2. In earlier versions you'll need to use `chunk {|o| o }`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jordan. I've added that.

Comment: Adrian, as you gain experience with Ruby you'll understand that it's not genius, just experience.

Comment: Sad that you are using `slice_when` with negative condition in the block rather than `chunk_while`.

Comment: @sawa is referring to [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while), introduced in Ruby v2.3.  (I had forgotten about that.) Yes, "sad", though perhaps not "grievious".